# MVC: Filter table by more than one parameter with the following code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, lambda

I'm using [PagedList.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc) to paginate a table and I added three filters on top of the table header. One for a brand, one for a category and another for a language. The following code works...

```
public ActionResult Index(string brand_name, string category_name, string language_name, 
                            int? page)
        {

            ViewData["brand_name"] = brand_name;
            ViewData["category_name"] = category_name;
            ViewData["language_name"] = language_name;

                    IPagedList<Material> onePageOfProducts = db.Materials
                    .Select(i => new Material
                    {
                        Brand = i.Brand,
                        Category = i.Category,
                        Language = i.Language,
                        Bco = i.Bco,
                        MaterialCod = i.MaterialCod,
                        Derivation = i.Derivation,
                        Artwork = i.Artwork,
                        BcoDelivery = i.BcoDelivery,
                        MaterialId = i.MaterialId
                    })
                    .Where(p =>
                        p.Brand.ToLower().Contains(brand_name.ToLower()) &&
                        p.Category.ToLower().Contains(category_name.ToLower()) &&
                        p.Language.ToLower().Contains(language_name.ToLower())
                    )
                    .OrderBy(i => i.MaterialCod)
                    .ToPagedList<Material>(pageNumber, defaultPageSize);

                return View("Index", onePageOfProducts);
         }
```

Now, the problem is that I **must** fill the the brand, category and language textboxes with data otherwise it will not filter when I **should** be able to filter by whatever I want, be it a brand alone or brand and language, and so on.

What's the most efficient way to filter using only what the user provides and avoid data not passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct IQueryable with several steps:

```
var query = db.Materials
    .Select(i => new Material
    {
        Brand = i.Brand,
        Category = i.Category,
        Language = i.Language,
        Bco = i.Bco,
        MaterialCod = i.MaterialCod,
        Derivation = i.Derivation,
        Artwork = i.Artwork,
        BcoDelivery = i.BcoDelivery,
        MaterialId = i.MaterialId
     });

if (brand_name != null)
    query = query.Where(p => p.Brand.ToLower().Contains(brand_name.ToLower());

if (category_name!= null)
    query = query.Where(p => p.Category.ToLower().Contains(category_name.ToLower());

if (language_name!= null)
    query = query.Where(p => p.Language.ToLower().Contains(language_name.ToLower());

IPagedList<Material> onePageOfProducts = query
    .OrderBy(i => i.MaterialCod)
    .ToPagedList<Material>(pageNumber, defaultPageSize);
```

Comment: Worked. I just changed the `if` statement for `if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(brand_name))` because it won't filter still if no data is added to the text boxes and lastly I added one more `)` to the `query` sets inside the `if`s.

Answer (score 1):

In conjunction to Alex's answer, you need to make the parameters nullable and defaults:

```
public ActionResult Index(string brand_name = null, string category_name = null, 
                          string language_name = null, int? page = null)
```

This way, if you don't pass, for example, `brand_name` into the method, then it will automatically be set to `null`, but you will also probably want to null check in your code, which is where Alex's answer comes in handy

Comment: Thanks. I'm using `if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(brand_name))` but I won't pass strings along so your answer comes handy. Do you think this is the most efficient way?

Comment: @Aoren Yes, I didn't realise when I read Alex's answer that it was actually incorrect. Yes, this is common practice.

Comment: About your answer, it says that "Optional parameters must appear after all required parameters".

Comment: @Aoren Yes, you must place all optional parameters at the end of the method signature. I've done this in my answer, so you're perhaps doing something different in your implementation?

Comment: Is because I wasn't nulling the `int? page`. My bad. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @Aoren No worries, glad you figured it out